# Attribute not found after filter is applied in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame and I am trying to apply a filter on it. However, I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't find pc#6 in [ss#1,pp#8,ct#3,pc#100]
```

Looking at the query plan, I have found this:

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [ct#3,cast(CASE WHEN isnull(pc#6) THEN 0 ELSE CASE WHEN NOT (pc#6 = 0015) THEN pc#6 ELSE cast(CASE WHEN (pc#6 = 0015) THEN 15 ELSE null as string) as decimal(5,0)) AS pc#100]
+- Filter ((date_processed#0 = 2019-01-31) && (ss#1 IN (c,p,l,b,i,a) || ((ss#1 = p) && (pp#8 = 500))))
   +- Relation[ct#3,pc#6,pp#8,ss#1] ParquetRelation: <db_name.table_name>

== Physical Plan ==
!Project [ct#3,cast(CASE WHEN isnull(pc#6) THEN 0 ELSE CASE WHEN NOT (pc#6 = 0015) THEN pc#6 ELSE cast(CASE WHEN (pc#6 = 0015) THEN 15 ELSE null as string) as decimal(5,0)) AS pc#100]
+- Filter (ss#1 IN (c,p,l,b,i,a) || ((ss#1 = p) && (pp#8 = 500)))
   +- Project [ss#1,pp#8,ct#3,cast(CASE WHEN isnull(pc#6) THEN 0 ELSE CASE WHEN NOT (pc#6 = 0015) THEN pc#6 ELSE cast(CASE WHEN (pc#6 = 0015) THEN 15 ELSE null as string) as decimal(5,0)) AS pc#100
      +- Scan ParquetRelation: <db_name>.<table_name>[pc#6,pp#8,ct#3,ss#1] InputPaths: <removed_text>
```

Note that I have masked some names because of our company confidentiality policy and I have removed unnecessary parts to simplify the problem and to have more clarity.

As you can see, pc#6 is being replaced by pc#100 in the Project. In the optimised plan, everything seems to be perfectly fine to me. However, in the physical plan the project is copied as a child of the filter, and I do not know why. I think that because of that, pc#6 is replaced by pc#100 in the first project applied (below the filter), and then it is not available in the top node project (hence the error).

Am I correct? Why is this happening? It seems like the optimised plan is perfectly fine but the Physical automatically creates that project which introduces an error... Could this be a Spark bug?

By the way, I am using Spark 1.6.0.

**Edit:** I have tried placing a persist on the dataframe just after the Relation node (before applying the Filter). That change the leaf of the plan to `InMemoryColumnarTableScan` instead of `Scan ParquetRelation` and for some reason, the additional Project is not created and the error disappears.

I still would like to understand what is happening here if anyone has any idea.

Comment: Can you try to write a simple snippet which minimally reproduces this problem?

Comment: Funny thing is I have tested this code in two different clusters (and locally in my laptop) and this is only happening in one of the clusters. So I don't really know how to reproduce it. What I have seen is that the physical plan is different in the environment that throws this error... (and that is the one I have posted here)

Comment: Spark works in mysterious ways...

Comment: Indeed. Also, I have tried searching in the Catalyst optimisations for any rule that could be creating that additional projection, but if does not make sense to me that it appears only in the physical plan... I would expect it to be created in the Optimised one already...